# Can't figure out DNS configuration for Static IP on Groovy

Tags: netplan, 20.10

I just set up Groovy server on a Pi4 and the configuration seems to be completely different than what I'm used to ... ex: `resolv.conf` is no longer involved in DNS config.

I followed instructions that I found and modified `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` to the following:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [192.168.0.6/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1]
            match:
                driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

After running `netplan apply` & `systemctl restart networking`, DNS isn't working. ex:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.6-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ dig google.com @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.16.6-Ubuntu <<>> google.com @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20363
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     85  IN  A   172.217.4.174

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 10 16:10:07 PST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Why isn't it using my configured DNS address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> systemctl restart networking
> This is not required (and I would not expect it to do anything except return an error).

As for why DNS isn't working: check the output of `resolvectl`.  Do you have the correct DNS servers listed in the output?

Also, what are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: I don't think either of those are applicable in recent versions of Ubuntu - hence my confusion:
`$ resolvctl`
`zsh: command not found: resolvctl`
`$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`
`cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please check the spelling of `resolvectl`.

Comment: As for `/etc/resolv.conf`, this file MUST exist, and its absence is the root of your problem.

Comment: You are actually correct - 1) I misspelled `resolvectl` and 2) everything works with the symlink in place, even with the `resolvconf` package removed